# Mysql query using where and group by clause

Tags: mysql

I have the following table.

```
mysql> select * from consumer9;
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Service_ID | Service_Type | consumer_feedback |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|        100 | Computing    |                -1 |
|         35 | Printer      |                 0 |
|         73 | Computing    |                -1 |
|         50 | Data         |                 0 |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

I want to use `GROUP BY` clause in my project. I am getting an error when I am using the query:

```
SELECT  Service_ID, Service_Type, SUM(consumer_feedback) 
FROM consumer9 
GROUP BY Service_ID 
WHERE Service_Type=Printer;
```

Error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'where  Service_Type=Printer' at line 1

Answer (score 47):

The following query should work.

```
select Service_ID, Service_Type, sum(consumer_feedback) 
from consumer9 
where Service_Type=Printer
group by Service_ID, Service_Type;
```

Remember, the where clause goes before the group by clause and all non-aggregated terms in the select part will have to be present in the group by clause.

Answer (score 13):

Use the `having` clause instead of `where`

```
SELECT  Service_ID, Service_Type, SUM(consumer_feedback) 
FROM consumer9 
GROUP BY Service_ID 
HAVING Service_Type='Printer';
```

Regards.

Comment: Bad answer, 20 seconds with HAVING when a WHERE took 0.0005. I just try with a syntax similar at this post multiple time.

Comment: HAVING works as well, but may be better suited for working with the derived quantity (here a contrived example) `SUM(consumer_feedback) AS total ... HAVING total > 0` that WHERE can't access.

Answer (score 0):

With sub-select:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Service_ID, Service_Type, SUM(consumer_feedback) 
  FROM consumer9 
  GROUP BY Service_ID
) as IService
WHERE IService.Service_Type=Printer;
```