# how check id is in the group_concat field?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which return  files and their tags and subcategories from some table , i want get files with special tag id.

```
SELECT file.id,file.title,content,comments,likes,visit,
                    group_concat(distinct sub_category_name ) as subCategoryName,
                    group_concat(distinct sub_category.id ) as subCatId,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct tag_name order by tag_id) as tag_name,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct tag_id order by tag_id) as tags_id
                     FROM file
                    LEFT JOIN file_subcat on file_subcat.file_id= file.id
                    LEFT JOIN sub_category on sub_category.id=file_subcat.subcat_id
                    LEFT JOIN tag_file tf1 on tf1.file_id=file.id
                    LEFT JOIN tag on tag_id=tag.id
                    group by file.id
                    HAVING tags_id LIKE ?
                    ORDER BY file.id DESC
```

if i use this query and if tags_id equal to 6 this return 6,16,...
how can change this query to get files that have that tag id?
and i dont want change the query from base, because i want show each file tags and sub categories and this query seems effiecient since i dont need multiple query.
the results set is something like this

```
file_id      tags_id
 1           6,15,16
 2           7,20,26 
 3           8,9,10
```

if i haved this in table i could use where an In() but because to get this result i used group by and having and it seems can't use IN or BETWEEN in having clause.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loved this question, try this,

```
SELECT file.id,file.title,content,comments,likes,visit,
                    group_concat(distinct sub_category_name ) as subCategoryName,
                    group_concat(distinct sub_category.id ) as subCatId,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct tag_name order by tag_id) as tag_name,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct tag_id order by tag_id) as tags_id
                     FROM file
                    LEFT JOIN file_subcat on file_subcat.file_id= file.id
                    LEFT JOIN sub_category on sub_category.id=file_subcat.subcat_id
                    LEFT JOIN tag_file tf1 on tf1.file_id=file.id
                    LEFT JOIN tag on tag_id=tag.id
                    group by file.id
                    HAVING  FIND_IN_SET('16', tags_id)
                    ORDER BY file.id DESC
```

replace <'16'> with whatever ID /Value you want, I'm sure you will fetch it
you can also exclude particular value in GROUP_CONCAT by

```
 HAVING  !FIND_IN_SET('16', tags_id)
```

Comment: I knew it would work. I too had exact same requirement long ago. cheers !

Comment: it's return 161 to? if yes then it's not the solution

Comment: '161' would certainly have '16' in group_concat string, then it would return !

Comment: if return's it's not the solution cause i can do it with like. but i test it now and didn't return. if you can test it

Comment: I checked it, if you pass 16, it wont return records with '161', unless that string already has '16' along with '161'. should I send you my tested queries ?

Answer (score 1):

Forget using the concatenated values.  Why search through strings when you can just do:

```
HAVING SUM(tag_id = ?) > 0
```

This saves all the string operations.  Plus, if `tag_id` is an integer, you can do the comparison as a number, rather than converting values back and forth between types.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your SQL, it appears as if you're using a LIKE operator. Using the LIKE operator will search for something similar, or equal to the specified variable (LET ? = variable), try changing your query around to use a direct comparison operator such as = (is equal to), something like;

```
SELECT file.id,file.title,content,comments,likes,visit,
                group_concat(distinct sub_category_name ) as subCategoryName,
                group_concat(distinct sub_category.id ) as subCatId,
                GROUP_CONCAT(distinct tag_name order by tag_id) as tag_name,
                GROUP_CONCAT(distinct tag_id order by tag_id) as tags_id
                 FROM file
                LEFT JOIN file_subcat on file_subcat.file_id= file.id
                LEFT JOIN sub_category on sub_category.id=file_subcat.subcat_id
                LEFT JOIN tag_file tf1 on tf1.file_id=file.id
                LEFT JOIN tag on tag_id=tag.id
                WHERE tags_id = ?
                group by file.id
                ORDER BY file.id DESC
```

Comment: can't use WHERE when use GROUP BY

Comment: Yes you can... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324879/mysql-query-using-where-and-group-by-clause

Comment: yes you are right, but in this case i can't because i cant use where before group by. and my data are related to group by