# sql query to count distinct

Tags: php, mysql

| candidate | position |
| --- | --- |
| john | referendum |
| mark | referendum |
| sofia | premier |
| john | referendum |
| john | referendum |
| sofia | premier |
| mark | referendum |
| sofia | premier |
| anna | premier |
| john | referendum |

hi guys, T need help with this query to count the results,
the output that I what will be:

```
john, for the referdum, has 4 votes
mark, for the referdum has 2 votes
sofia, for the premier has 3 votes
anna, for the premier has 1 votes
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    candidate, 
    position, 
    count(DISTINCT candidate) over (order by position) AS votes_received 
from votes;
```

this was my query, but says:

> This version of MariaDB does not yet support 'COUNT (DISTINCT) aggregate as window function

thanks for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql query using where and group by clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324879/mysql-query-using-where-and-group-by-clause)

Comment: What version of mariadb are you on  - select version(), btw distinct is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to look at [GROUP BY](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx), something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total`, `candidate`, `position`
FROM `votes`
GROUP BY `candidate`, `position`
```

(back ticks, just in case...)